# IOS 7.1.1 ibeacon detection time when app is not at foreground

Tags: ios, ibeacon

David's blog mentions in http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/03/12/ios7-1-background-detection-times.html, that the background detection time is around 15 mins on iOS7.1. When I am testing iOS 7.1.1 on iphone5, I notice that 1) In foreground, like others suggested, almost instantly; 2) when app is not in foreground,but another app is, around 15 mins to respond, 3) phone awaken while locked, result seems inconsistent, which varies from 1-2 seconds to 7-8 seconds 4) phone not awaken, results are also inconsistent, varies from 4-5 seconds to 10+, much slower than 3).

Anyone is experiencing the difference between 2),3) and 4)?

Regards
Hammer

Comment: What do you mean by 4) "phone not awaken"?  Is the app in the background or foreground in this case?

Comment: David, 4) is when app is running, press the btn to lock the screen and wait till display is off.

Comment: so 3) is phone is locked, but display is on

Comment: Btw, I was using Radius network's USB beacon for testing

Comment: testing on Radius' virtual beacon on mac usually has better respond time than the physical USB beacon.

Comment: From the iOS perspective, I think case 4 is the same as the app being in the background.  I don't think there is any special treatment for turning off the display -- only turning on the display.

Comment: Thanks. Then there are differences as for the responding time in cases 2),3),4) on ios 7.1.1, where for 3)4), it seems no longer abt 15 mins. Could u test to confirm? or update the blog if necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not done the tests needed to measure foreground detection times you mention, but you could do these tests yourself using the same open source code linked from my [first blog post on the subject](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html), and following the described procedure.  I would love to hear the results!

Understand that the main reason Radius Networks has not done such tests to characterize foreground detection times is because the variation does not appear to be so big. (Plus the tests are time consuming to perform.)  In your observations, you report variations from 0 to 8 seconds.  These delays are very small compared to the background delay of up to 15 minutes.